# Como listar valores usando ng-repeat usando AngularJS e JsonResult ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, angularjs, ng-repeat

Boas Amigos! Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação MVC que devolve JSON para um controlador AngularJS, ocorre que estes valores são valores unitários e listas.
E na hora de renderizar na view, apenas o valores unitários funcionam. O valores que são uma lista, renderiza uma lista de campos vazios. Vale lembrar que todos os dados estão sendo carregados corretamente no controller AngularJS.

Angular.

```
var app = angular.module('FileApp', []);        
app.service('ngFileService', function ($http) {        
  this.getFileByFileCode = function (fileCodigo) {
    var response = $http.get("/Files/GetFile?fileCodigo=" + fileCodigo);
    return response;
  };

});

app.controller('ngFileController', function ($scope, ngFileService) {                
  $scope.filterFileCode = "";

  $scope.getFilteredFile = function () {
    var promise = ngFileService.getFileByFileCode($scope.filterFileCode);
    promise.then(function (resp) {
      $scope.File = resp.data;       
      $scope.Message = "Call is Completed Successfully";
    }, function (err) {
      $scope.Message = "Call Failed " + err.status;
    });
  };
});
```

HTML

```
    <tr>
      <td>Enter Search Value:</td>
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="filterFileCode" class="form- 
     control" ng-change="getFilteredFile()" /></td>
    </tr>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Documentos Gerais File</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>CTB</th>
        <th>COM</th>
        <th>Site</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="f in File">
        <td>Documentos</td>
        <td>{{f.FileCTB}}</td>
        <td>{{f.FileCOM}}</td>
        <td>{{f.FileSite}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Aqui vai alguns print:
[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPsFs.jpg)
[Front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtiyH.jpg)
[Lista vazia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbQmz.jpg)

**DataCriacao: "/Date(-62135596800000)/"
DataFim: "06/07/2018"
DataInicio: "26/06/2018"
DescricaoServico: null
FileCOM: (2) [true, false]
FileCTB: (2) [false, false]
FileCodigo: 190562
FileCodigoId: 0
FileCodigoNv: null
FileMimeType: null
FileSite: (2) [false, false]**

Comment: apresente o gerado na sua pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu encontrei essa solução.

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Documentos</td>
    <td>Comandos</td>
    <td><span ng-repeat="(key, value) in File.FileCTB track by $index"> 
         {{value}}</span></td>
    <td><span ng-repeat="(key, value) in File.FileCOM track by $index"> 
         {{value}}</span></td>
    <td><span ng-repeat="(key, value) in File.FileSite track by $index"> 
         {{value}}</span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```